# Image only grid list

Tags: html, css

Issue with grid shown on image below

I want images with ratio 1:1 and 2:1

Issue is that the 1:1 have 226px:242px
When I give 100% width and height to 1:1 then the 2:1 will align differently.

[image: CurrentGrid]

The grid html code should look like this.
"Using object-fit is good"

```
<grid>
    <container ratio="1:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch?id=1">
    </container>
    <container ratio="2:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/100/arch?id=1">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch?id=1">
    </container>
</grid>
```

Expected grid should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Images are a little tricky because the aspects, best way to but the image perfectly is to add `max-width: 100%` and let the height `auto` or you can use `max-height` is idea is to play with the `width` and let the image decide the `height` or vise versa, you problem can be fixed by this code

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed it by my own :D

```css
body {
    margin: 24px;
}

grid {
    display: grid;
    margin: 0;
    grid-gap: 24px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

container {
    position: relative;
}

container > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}

[ratio="1:1"] {
    grid-column-end: span 3;
}

[ratio="2:1"] {
    grid-column-end: span 6;
}

[ratio="2:1"] > img {
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<grid>
    <container ratio="1:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=1">
    </container>
    <container ratio="2:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/2000/1000/arch?id=2">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=3">
    </container>

    <container ratio="2:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/2000/1000/arch?id=4">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=5">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=6">
    </container>

    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=7">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=8">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=9">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=10">
    </container>

    <container ratio="1:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=11">
    </container>
    <container ratio="1:1">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch?id=12">
    </container>
    <container ratio="2:1">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/2000/1000/arch?id=13">
    </container>
</grid>
```

Enjoy! :)

Btw... The grid is for my FrameWork - MatDesign

[image]